# Print acronymos

Tags: acronyms

I want to print acronyms, but is not working

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\acrodef{CNO}{Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones}
\begin{document}
Sometext \ac{CNO} caca \ac{CNO}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de Acrónimos}
\printacronym
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should only use `\acrodef` if you *don't* want a list. `\printacronym` is not a command of the package, if you take it out, it works.

Comment: But is not printing anyway

Comment: no, it doesn't; that's the point of using `\acrodef` and not the standard `\begin{acronym}` ;) see below for how to get a list anyway

Answer (score 5):

You could switch to the [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package. There are some differences with the commands you used, but the usage is very straightforward and easy to understand. Using the command `\printacronyms`, it creates an automatic section with a list of the acronyms. This is the result:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{cno}{
  short = CNO ,
  long  = Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones
}

\begin{document}
Some text \ac{cno}, also \ac{cno} and more text

\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the list anyway, the basic usage could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section*{List of acronyms}
\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{List of acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{CNO}{Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones}
\end{acronym}


\section{Main text}

Sometext \ac{CNO} caca \ac{CNO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Florian. But is not working now with nomenclatures

Comment: The code I posted compiles here just fine -- what precisely doesn't work for you?

Comment: @NicolásSacco: `Not working` is not really helpful.

Comment: How do I put the acronym list in something like the listoffigures?

Comment: How can I change the position of the list?

Comment: yes, sure, just move the `acronym`-environment to where you want it. I've also added the code for listoffigures, even though I'd personally put it in the TOC instead.